# Is there a way to mock refetch in MockedProvider - Apollo Client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-testing-library

Here is how I am using MockedProvider. How can I mock refetch in mocks array?

```
const mocks = [{
        request: {
            query: GET_USERS_BY_FACILITY,
            variables: {
                facility: 300
            }
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                GetUsersByFacility: [{
                    nuId: 'Q916983',
                    userName: faker.internet.userName(),
                    profileKey: 'testKey',
                    profileValue: 'testValue',
                    __typename: 'FacilityUser'
                }]
            }
        },
        refetch: () => {
            return {
                data: {
                    GetUsersByFacility: [{
                        nuId: 'Q916983',
                        userName: faker.internet.userName(),
                        profileKey: 'testKey',
                        profileValue: 'testValue',
                        __typename: 'FacilityUser'
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This test case calls refetch function when delete event is triggered.

```
 it('should be able to click on delete user', async () => {
        const {getByTestId} = render(
            <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
                <Users selectedFacility={300}/>
            </MockedProvider>)

        await wait(0)
        fireEvent.click(getByTestId('btnDelete'))
    })
```

I have been trying different ways, none seems to work. I get error message as **TypeError: Cannot read property 'refetch' of undefined**.

Thank you very much in hope of an answer.

Regards,
--Rajani

Comment: I don't see where you're calling refetch.

Comment: refetch is called in "Users" component when click on delete button using 'fireEvent'.

Comment: Can you post that code? Is it working with a regular Apollo Provider?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit late to answer, but if you have't got any answers yet, you would refer to the way I solved.

Please note that this might not be the correct answer.

---

- You can find this code in [react-apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#mockedprovider)

```
const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_DOG_QUERY,
      variables: {
        name: 'Buck',
      },
    },
    result: () => {
      // do something, such as recording that this function has been called
      // ...
      return {
        data: {
          dog: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' },
        },
      }
    },
  },
];
```

- I make my refetch testcode based on this phrase `// do something, such as recording that this function has been called`

This is my mock example.

```js
let queryCalled = false

const testingData = (value) => ({
  data: {....}
})

const TESTING_MOCK = {
  request: {
    query: TESTING_QUERY,
    variables: { some: "variables" },
  },
  result: () => {
    if (queryCalled) return testingData("refetched");
    else {
      queryCalled = true;
      return testingData("first fetched");
    }
  },
};
```

- This component refetches data when the button is clicked. I designed my test code in this order

  1. when it's rendered for the first time, it fetches the mock data .
     => In the code above, `queryCalled` is `false` so, it reassigns `queryCalled` as `true` and return the "first fetched" mock data,
  2. when a click event occurs, refetch occurs too.
     => On the same principle the mock data returns "refetched" mock data.

My testcode example is here

```js
it("refetch when clicked save button.", async () => {
  const mocks = [TESTING_MOCK];
  let utils: RenderResult = render(<SomeTestingComponent mocks={mocks} />);

  await waitForNextTick(); //for getting a data, not loading

  const titleInput = utils.getByDisplayValue("first fetched");

  const saveBtn = utils.getByText("save");
  fireEvent.click(saveBtn);
  await waitForElement(() => utils.getByDisplayValue("refetched"));
})
```

---

Please let me know if you have any other suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that might still run into this, the solution to make refetch work in your tests is to use the `newData` method while keeping track of the query having been called.

I don't know if this is a bug in the MockedProvider implementation, but I was banging my head against the wall trying to make `newData` work together with `result`, but it turns out that `newData` completely overrides `result`.

A working solution (tested with useQuery and Apollo Client 3) would be something like this:

```
let queryCalled = false;
const refetchMock = {
  request: {
    query: YOUR_QUERY
  },
  newData: () => {
    if (queryCalled) {
      return { 
        data: {
          // your refetched data
        }
      }; 
    } else {
      queryCalled = true;
      return { 
        data: {
          // your first fetched data
        } 
      }; 
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `newData` solution didn't work for me with apollo client `@2.6`.

As a workaround, for the few tests that utilize `refetch` I had to physically mock the `useQuery` function and provide mock functions for the return of `refetch`; for our custom hook (where an overridden `useQuery` hook is exported as `default`), it looked something like this:

```
import * as useQueryModule from '~/hooks/useQuery';

describe('test the thing', () => {
    let useQuerySpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Spy on the `useQuery` function so we can optionally provide alternate behaviour.
        useQuerySpy = jest.spyOn(useQueryModule, 'default');
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      // Restore any mocked behaviour
      useQuerySpy.mockRestore();
    });

    it('does a thing', async () => {
        const refetchedApolloResponse = buildResponse(refetchData) // some function to build the shape / data of apollo response
        const initialApolloResponse = buildResponse(initialData) // some function to build the shape / data of apollo response
     
       const mockRefetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: refetchedApolloResponse });
       useQuerySpy.mockReturnValue({ data: initialApolloResponse, refetch: mockRefetch });

      // Assert stuff
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution did not work for me and not sure whether it will work or not because it didn't work in my case.

```
let queryCalled = false

const testingData = (value) => ({
  data: {....}
})

const TESTING_MOCK = {
  request: {
    query: TESTING_QUERY,
    variables: { some: "variables" },
  },
  result: () => {
    if (queryCalled) return testingData("refetched");
    else {
      queryCalled = true;
      return testingData("first fetched");
    }
  },
};
```

So I solved it by another way which is:

```
const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_DOG_QUERY,
      variables: {
        name: 'Buck',
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        dog: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' },
      },
    },
    newData: jest.fn(() => ({
      data: {
        dog: { id: '1', name: 'Refetched-Buck', breed: 'refetched-bulldog' },
      },
    })),
  },
];
```

It worked like a charm for me.